# MFC MDI Opening view from MainFrame.cpp

Tags: c++, mfc, mdi

I am trying to open a new view on button click. First a dialog is shown and when I click ok the view should be shown. It's implemented in MainFrame.cpp.
Here's the code:

```
void CMainFrame::OnBtnUnosProizvoda()
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
    UnosProizvodaDlg dlg;
    if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        CView* pCurrentView = GetActiveView();

    // We are about to change the view, so we need a pointer to the runtime class
    CRuntimeClass* pNewView;

    // We will process a form
    pNewView = RUNTIME_CLASS(CPrikaz2View);
        CCreateContext crtContext;

    // We have a new view now. So we initialize the context
        crtContext.m_pNewViewClass = pNewView;
    // No need to change the document. We keep the current document
    crtContext.m_pCurrentDoc   = GetActiveDocument();

    CPrikaz2View* pNewViewer = STATIC_DOWNCAST(CPrikaz2View, CreateView(&crtContext));

    // Now we can create a new view and get rid of the previous one
    if( pNewViewer != NULL )
    {
        pNewViewer->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

        pNewViewer->OnInitialUpdate();
        SetActiveView(pNewViewer);
        RecalcLayout();

    //  pCurrentView->DestroyWindow();
    }
    }

}
```

The new View should be docked as the rest of the views. However this is the result I get:

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQWeH.png)

It seems to get stuck to the top left corner of the mainframe instead of the childframe. How to fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to call `OnFileNew()` to create new MDI child or tab?

Comment: To create new MDI child.

Answer (score 0):

Your project has a class derived from `CWinAppEx`. The name of this class is something like `CMyApp` (yours would be named differently). Add the following override for `OnFileNew`

```
class CMyApp : public CWinAppEx
{
public:
    CMyApp();
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    virtual int ExitInstance();

    void OnFileNew() //<== add this
    {
        CWinAppEx::OnFileNew();
    }
    ...
};
```

Now you can create new mdi child

```
void CMainFrame::OnBtnUnosProizvoda()
{
    theApp.OnFileNew();
}
```

Comment: That works! I have another thing though, this OnFileNew() will be called after a dialog return IDOK. I need to pass some data from the dialog to the ChildFrame. How to do that?

Comment: Your second question is unrelated. You can accept this question and ask a separate question. Give more information about your setup. You usually need to change document data, but `CFrameWnd::GetActiveDocument()` may return `NULL`, you have to take different route. Check the return value.

Comment: It returns 'NULL' because there's no active documents nor views at this point. Could you give me a bit more of information on how to implement it, I'm having trouble doing it?

Comment: `CFrameWnd::GetActiveDocument()` may return `NULL` even after new document has been added. **You should give more information**. It's not clear what you have and what you want, I assume you want a pointer to `CMyDocument` and `CMyChild`